# Bootstrap 3 Datatable Styling in Asp.Net getting overwritten somehow

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

Just trying to get the Bootstrap 3 Theme for Datatables (https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html) to function on a new Asp.Net MVC application and I think styles are getting overwritten somehow.

From what I understand from this page I need to include the bootstrap.min.css file and the dataTable.bootstrap.min.css file which I've done here in my Bundle Config,

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on bundling, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at https://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js",
                  "~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css",
                  "~/Content/DataTables/css/jquery.dataTables.css",
                  "~/Content/DataTables/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css"));
    }
}
```

I've read various things, I've tried removing the "~/Content/DataTables/css/jquery.dataTables.css" from my css bundle as that seems to conflict as well. That didn't do anything for me either though. The datatable initialization works fine and I get this,

[image: Datatable Styling Error]

You can tell its trying to apply the bootstrap styling with the icons conflicting. But I can't tell why the styling isn't automatically applying.

Here is my table setup,

```
<table class="table" id="anthony-transactions">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="btn btn-default">
                Edit
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>May 2017 | Wellness Summit</td>
        <td>
            <span class="text-success">
                +$10.00
            </span>
        </td>
        <td>Amazon</td>
        <td>6/7/2017</td>
        <td>
            <div class="btn btn-danger">
                Delete
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="btn btn-default">
                Edit
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>Stanford Research Study</td>
        <td>
            <span class="text-success">
                +$15.00
            </span>
        </td>
        <td>Amazon</td>
        <td>6/10/2017</td>
        <td>
            <div class="btn btn-danger">
                Delete
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="btn btn-default">
                Edit
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>Steam Game</td>
        <td>
            <span class="text-danger">
                -$10.00
            </span>
        </td>
        <td>Game</td>
        <td>6/1/2017</td>
        <td>
            <div class="btn btn-danger">
                Delete
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="btn btn-default">
                Edit
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>Century Link Stream Service</td>
        <td>
            <span class="text-success">
                +$100.00
            </span>
        </td>
        <td>Visa</td>
        <td>6/1/2017</td>
        <td>
            <div class="btn btn-danger">
                Delete
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

And initialization script,

```
@section Scripts{
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#anthony-transactions").DataTable();
    });
</script>
}
```

I'm looking to get this style look and feel from the theme where you can see the pagination, search, and results per page dropdown are styled as well,

[image: Goal Theme]

Comment: Can you do it without the class of `table` added to the table? I would guess that's why Bootstrap's default table styling is applying as well as DataTables' Bootstrap theme.

Comment: @mark.hch Looks like that's not the problem, just tried removing it.

Comment: Bummer... was hoping it'd be an easy fix for you. In that case, I would definitely steer you down the path that @AlexanderHiggins mentioned (check Dev Tools for the CSS that's applied to the table, and try to narrow down the rule that's screwing with it).

Comment: Got it solved thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was never able to isolate the minutia of what was going wrong, but I had installed datatables through my Nuget Package manager so I just rewound and removed the self installation and did it myself only installing the needed files and bundling them and it seemed to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the icon and from the context menu choose inspect element, which will open the developer console in your browser. The icon in the example has its style being applied by boot strap using ::after. Once you have the element inspected in the right side of the window you will see the style sheet rules. Here you will likely find that another css rule is being applied causing the icons to conflict. The conflicting rule will have a hyperlink to the document containing the CSS and the line number of the rule that is causing the conflict.

Also, the table in the example has form classes applied to it "table table-striped table-bordered dataTable" where the table in your markup on has "table" applied to it.

Interestingly this table has one of the icons in your header https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html and this table has the other https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html

The first table defines in /css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css

```
table.dataTable thead .sorting::after {
opacity: 0.2;
content: "\e150";
```

}

The second example defines in /css/jquery.dataTables.min.css:

```
table.dataTable thead .sorting {
background-image: url("../images/sort_both.png");
```

}

These rules conflict and having both style sheets will result in both of the icons you are seeing.

[image]

Comment: The thing that is throwing me off with this because I am doing that, but I don't see bootstrap datatable css rules being overwritten, its like they are simply not being applied in some areas whereas they are in others.

Comment: If you are certain the rule isn't being overwritten, inspect some nearby elements to see if rules are being applied to that. You can also uncheck the rule to deactivate and then look on the computed tab to see what is actually being applied.

Comment: Can't find any rules that are being overwritten as I check and uncheck things. Does it seem like my bundling was setup correctly?

Comment: Wait. There might actually be hope. I used Nuget to get my datatable files and I just tested an empty project installing the bare minimum and it seemed to work. Should be able to work off of this.

Comment: Try applying all the class and attributes from the demo table to yours. Your table only has the class "table". The demo has the class "table table-striped table-bordered dataTable"

Comment: Yeah, me too. There are two different conflicting style sheet rules in dataTables.bootstrap.min.css and jquery.dataTables.min.css. You can accept the answer as the correct solution so others know how to fix the same problem. Thanks